# cash register 'out of balance'

Tags: phrase-meaning, jargon

What does it mean when a cash register is ***out of balance***?  I cannot seem to find "*out of balance*" in dictionaries.  Could it be a technical jargon?

Comment: does it maybe mean that it's tilted? that it's not on a flat surface but sloping more to one side?

Answer (score 2):

A modern cash register maintains a record of the transactions that it has "registered".  This record of transactions is, in accounting terms, a "ledger" or "subledger".  The "ledger" has "balances".  The initial balance, plus the net amount that has been received, should equal the final balance.  In other words, the cash register can tell you how much money should be "in the till".  If the final balance does not correspond to what is in the till, the "cash register is out of balance".  A mistake was made somewhere along the line.

Comment: So, this usage of "*out of balance*" is accounting/finance jargon?

Comment: @meatie -- Yes, this usage of "out of balance" is accounting jargon.  It is also jargon used by store clerks.  My guess is that the term was used before accounting became a major profession distinct from bookkeeping and storekeeping.

Answer (score 1):

In all sorts of financial contexts *balance* refers to the requirement that two values must be equal.

For instance, in an account you maintain with your bank your *balance* is the difference between the money you have put into the account and the money you have taken out in the form of checks or charges or withdrawals. That difference (positive, you hope!) ‘balances’ the account: added to what you have taken out it equals what you have put in.

In the same way, if you run a business, your books are periodically audited to make sure they are in *balance*: that assets balance liabilities and revenues balance disbursements.

A cashier’s register is similarly audited once or twice per shift to make sure that the amount of cash and checks and charges in the till balances the  value of goods shown as sold on the accounting tape. If these values are not equal, the register is ‘out of balance’.

Comment: So, this usage of "*out of balance*" is accounting/finance jargon?

Comment: No. It is a very common metaphor used in lots of contexts; this is what it means in a money context. It's not jargon at all: everybody who has a bank account or a credit cared or has to pay bills every month understands it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities.

1: It's tilted.

2: It's a jargon term for not having the amount of money in the cashbox as the machine's own records say it should. Many modern cash registers keep a tally of how much money should have been put in and taken out, and at the end of the shift, the worker takes that *balance* and it gets checked against the amount that's actually in the cashbox. This lets management know if someone is perhaps skimming money from it, or being forgetful in handing out the right amount of change (which can make customers upset if they notice).

Some links that don't *quite* use "out of balance" as a term, but do lend plausibility to the second explanation:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-balance-cash-register-transactions.html

http://retail.about.com/od/storeoperations/qt/drawer_balance.htm (This one is especially helpful.)